# Declaring a variable without specifying primitive type in Java OR changing an object to it's corresponding primitive type

Tags: java

I want to be able to declare a variable in Java, however I do not know what the type of the variable will be until an if, if else statement is evaluated.

I know that you can't declare the variable within each if statement because it will be out of scope outside of the if statement.

The variable also **MUST** be a primitive datatype instead of an object (e.g. Integer, Double, String)

```
// do not know datatype yet
(type) signalValue;

        // signal is Integer object
        if (SysjInput[1] instanceof Integer) {
                signalValue = (int) SysjInput[1];

        // signal is String object
        } else if (SysjInput[1] instanceof String) {
                signalValue = (String) SysjInput[1];

        // signal is Double object  
        } else if (SysjInput[1] instanceof Double) {
                signalValue = (double) SysjInput[1];
        }

System.out.println(signalValue)
```

I have also tried something like this:

```
Object signalValue;
signalValue = 123;
```

It will convert it to an Integer object and I would need some way to convert it to a primitive type.

Comment: You test for `signalValue` being a `String`, yet say it has to be "a primitive datatype instead of an object (e.g. `Integer`, `Double`, `String`)", meaning that your `String` if block will never execute given your specifications. Also, why is using objects not okay? Finally, you can use a primitive object (`Double`, `Float`...) as a primitive, and Java will auto-unbox it for you into the primitive required.

Comment: Why do you need it to be `int` instead of `Integer`? Auto unboxing will automatically do that task for you wherever required anyway.

Comment: That's my mistake, String is fine, but I would like the Integer and Double to be primitive types if possible

Comment: Usually usage of `instanceof` means the program can be re-designed. How do you intend to use `signalValue`?

Comment: The reason why I want it to be a primitive type is because I plan to send 'signalValue' to a Python program through sockets. I think it'd be easier to work with primitive types rather than an Object because both languages will understand primitive types. (I have not actually tested if Python will understand an Integer or Double object yet.)

Comment: If you're sending through Sockets, I'd imagine you'd be sending `byte`s, in which case `Number`, which `Integer`, `Double`, etc. extend from, has a `.toBytes()` method, which should give the bytes for whatever number type you have. String also has `.getBytes()`.

Answer (score 3):

Initializing with Object class should work, I tryed this and worked just fine:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    Object t;

    t = 4;
    int d = (int) t;
    int e = d + d;

    System.out.println(e);
}
```

output: 8